# Android DatePickerDialog wait for dismiss

Tags: android, for-loop, wait, dismiss, datepickerdialog

Today imma trying to develop a simple app, which will ask the user to insert 2 dates by using the DatePickerDialog through a button, and then execute a query into a Database:

```
        Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


          Da = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, DADateSetListener, 2014, 8, 24);
          Da.show();
          Da.setTitle("Date FROM");

          A = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, ADateSetListener, 2014, 10, 24);

          A.show();
          A.setTitle("Date TO");


          //Erase the List View
          List.setAdapter(null);

          prepareProgressBar();
          query();

        }

    });
```

My only question is:
How can i wait for the DatePickerDialog do dismiss or wait for the user to enter the input and then execute the query ?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html):

> We recommend that you use `DialogFragment` to host each time or date picker.

The docs include a sample class that extends `DialogFragment` (located [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#TimePickerFragment)):

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

And you would show it like this (again, code from [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#ShowingTheTimePicker)):

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

And, as an added bonus, this dialog would indeed be **[modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window)** (what you were going for when you said "wait for dismiss").

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple dialog I don't see why you don't use the default listeners:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd;
dpd.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Handle dismiss
    }
});
dpd.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Handle clicks
        return false;
    }
});
```